# what is the chainlink VRF randomness details for xDai/Gnosis chain?

Tags: chainlink, randomness, vrf, gnosis-chain

I looked into docs of chainlink but I couldn't find the VRF details for xDai/Gnosis chain network.

Could you please help me find the following details?

```
Chainlink VRF Coordinator address:

LINK token address:
  
Key Hash:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chainlink VRF is currently not available on Gnosis Chain. For now, you can try it on the solutions listed [here](https://docs.chain.link/docs/vrf-contracts/)

Comment: that is a bummber, is there anyway it will be implemented in the future?